# IF AND function for entire columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Apologies in advance if this is ridiculously simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a Google sheet that is constantly updated with new data which is displayed in three columns (url, date, sessions). I'd like to create a new tab into which I pull this data across. I can't pull in specific cells because the data is constantly changing, so am trying to come up with a specific formula that will do the job for me.

`=IF(AND('raw data'!A:A="url", 'raw data'!B:B="date"),'raw data'!C:C,"NO DATA")`

As far as I can tell, the above query should pull the number of sessions for a specific page on a specific date, but I constantly seem to be getting "NO DATA" returned. In case it's not clear, I'd like to be able to get the value for CX where AX=url and BX=date.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please share a minimum reproducible sample of your sheet this way the community can have something to replicate your data.

Comment: I deleted my previous answer to avoid any confusion with the post.  Please share with me the error or please provide a minimum reproducible sample of your sheets please. This way I can understand why the formula did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, thanks for the help/suggestions. For anybody who stumbles upon this in the future, I ended up using the formula below, though it's possible that some of the other suggestions would have also done the job.

The C column on the raw data sheet contains the number of sessions of each page (ie, the data I was trying to pull across) while the C column of the new tab contains the URL (which is in column A on the raw data sheet). Column B of the raw data sheet is the date. I originally tried to use a cell in the new tab to check for the date (ie, "D1='raw data'B:B", where D1 was a cell containing the date I wanted the data for), but found that this caused major issues when sorting the data on the new tab and made it impossible to copy the formula across cells, so ended up using the TODAY function instead.

`=INDEX('raw data'!C:C,MATCH(1,(C1='raw data'!A:A)*(TODAY()-1='raw data'!B:B),0))`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without an example, but if you have an actual URL in column A and an actual Date in column B, then your formula will return "No Data" because of the way you have structured your formula.

"url" and "date" are strings.  Those actual strings must be the value in the cells for the formula to return the values in column C.

If this is the case, consider changing your formula to:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISURL(A1:A)+ISDATE(B1:B),C1:C,"NO DATA"))

Note that `AND` is not supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`.  I used `+` instead.

If you don't want "No Data" running down the length of Column C when the corresponding row in Column A is blank, you can add an ISBLANK function like so:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IF(ISURL(A1:A)+ISDATE(B1:B),C1:C,"NO DATA")))

In my opinion, this looks nicer.

If I have misunderstood the question and this does not actually address the problem you are having, let me know and please share an example so all can see what the issue is.